# Espresso tests fail randomly with AppNotIdleException

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

I'm writing very long-running UI/integration tests, intending to go through the entire functionality of my app under various configurations, and I'm having problems with the overall stability and performance of Espresso.

I've completed maybe 5-10% of the entire test suite I'm intending to have at the end, and it already takes 1-2 hours to run and sometimes randomly fails at arbitrary points. As the tests go on, I often notice the UI becoming very sluggish.

In case it's relevant: I'm using JUnit5 via `de.mannodermaus.gradle.plugins:android-junit5`, because I heavily depend on the "dynamic tests" feature of JUnit5, using `@TestFactory` and streams of `DynamicTest` / `DynamicNode`. This is because I have to repeat certain tests again and again with different parameters, and can't just write an additional `@Test` method for every possible combination of parameters.

Also, my test runner overrides `shouldWaitForActivitiesToComplete()` to return `false`, because my tests are written in such a way that one test picks up from where the other finished.

The most common reason for failure seems to be something along the lines of:

```
androidx.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'single click - At Coordinates: 539, 283 and precision: 16, 16' on view 'view.getId() is <2131297344/org.example.myapp.debug:id/topButton>'.
[...]
Caused by: androidx.test.espresso.AppNotIdleException: Looped for 9 iterations over 60 SECONDS. The following Idle Conditions failed MAIN_LOOPER_HAS_IDLED(last message: { when=-111ms callback=android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver target=android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler }).
```

The exact reason for the `AppNotIdleException` varies. The last time it was what you see above; before that, it had `DELAY_HAS_PAST` in place of `MAIN_LOOPER_HAS_IDLED`.

I don't believe my app itself has memory leaks, but I wonder if the way I'm writing tests causes memory over-consumption somehow, slowing the whole system down as memory becomes tight?

Notice how the exception says it only looped for 9 iterations over 60 seconds. (Another time it was 45 iterations.) When I search the web for this exception, I see other people having iterations in the thousands within the same 60-second window before Espresso gives up.

The entire stack trace from my last failed test run, from which I took the snippet above, is as follows:

```
androidx.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'single click - At Coordinates: 539, 283 and precision: 16, 16' on view 'view.getId() is <2131297344/org.example.myapp.debug:id/topButton>'.
at androidx.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:1)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.PerformExceptionHandler.handleSafely(PerformExceptionHandler.java:8)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.PerformExceptionHandler.handleSafely(PerformExceptionHandler.java:9)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$TypedFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:4)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:5)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:8)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.desugaredPerform(ViewInteraction.java:11)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:8)
at org.example.myapp.tests.modules.generic.AddLinesActivityTests.startAddingItem(AddLinesActivityTests.java:169)
at org.example.myapp.tests.modules.generic.AddLinesActivityTests.addItem(AddLinesActivityTests.java:149)
at org.example.myapp.tests.modules.generic.AddLinesActivityTests.testAddItemWithoutSerials(AddLinesActivityTests.java:104)
at org.example.myapp.tests.modules.generic.AddLinesActivityTests.testAddItem(AddLinesActivityTests.java:52)
at org.example.myapp.tests.modules.generic.AddLinesActivityTests.lambda$testAddAllItems$1(AddLinesActivityTests.java:44)
at org.example.myapp.tests.modules.generic.AddLinesActivityTests.$r8$lambda$KryLIinqeGZZnfUqLz3MKtYQH8g(Unknown Source:0)
at org.example.myapp.tests.modules.generic.AddLinesActivityTests$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.execute(Unknown Source:6)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:205)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:187)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:205)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:205)
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:503)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:133)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:236)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:437)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:285)
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:503)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:133)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:236)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:437)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:285)
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:503)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:133)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:236)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:437)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:285)
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:503)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:133)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:236)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachOrdered(ReferencePipeline.java:442)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:205)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:187)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:205)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:205)
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:503)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:133)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:236)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:437)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:285)
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:503)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:133)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:236)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachOrdered(ReferencePipeline.java:442)
at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:179)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1528)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1528)
Caused by: androidx.test.espresso.AppNotIdleException: Looped for 9 iterations over 60 SECONDS. The following Idle Conditions failed MAIN_LOOPER_HAS_IDLED(last message: { when=-111ms callback=android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver target=android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler }).
at androidx.test.espresso.IdlingPolicy.handleTimeout(IdlingPolicy.java:5)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:50)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:1)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.injectMotionEvent(UiControllerImpl.java:5)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendUp(MotionEvents.java:7)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendUp(MotionEvents.java:1)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.sendSingleTap(Tap.java:5)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.-$$Nest$smsendSingleTap(Unknown Source:0)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.sendTap(Tap.java:3)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:6)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:2)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:25)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.-$$Nest$mdoPerform(Unknown Source:0)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:7)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:1)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
```

Has anyone had similar experiences with Espresso?  How could I best troubleshoot this to find the cause?

EDIT:

Here's a second stack trace from another run:

```
androidx.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'single click - At Coordinates: 539, 553 and precision: 16, 16' on view ' displaying data matching: Item: cwms-testing-001 within adapter view matching: is assignable from class <class android.widget.AdapterView>'.
at androidx.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:1)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.PerformExceptionHandler.handleSafely(PerformExceptionHandler.java:8)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.PerformExceptionHandler.handleSafely(PerformExceptionHandler.java:9)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$TypedFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:4)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:5)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:8)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.desugaredPerform(ViewInteraction.java:11)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:8)
at androidx.test.espresso.DataInteraction.perform(DataInteraction.java:1)
at org.example.myapp.tests.modules.generic.AddLinesActivityTests.startAddingItem(AddLinesActivityTests.java:170)
at org.example.myapp.tests.modules.generic.AddLinesActivityTests.addItem(AddLinesActivityTests.java:149)
at org.example.myapp.tests.modules.generic.AddLinesActivityTests.testAddItemWithoutSerials(AddLinesActivityTests.java:88)
at org.example.myapp.tests.modules.generic.AddLinesActivityTests.testAddItem(AddLinesActivityTests.java:52)
at org.example.myapp.tests.modules.generic.AddLinesActivityTests.lambda$testAddAllItems$1(AddLinesActivityTests.java:44)
at org.example.myapp.tests.modules.generic.AddLinesActivityTests.$r8$lambda$KryLIinqeGZZnfUqLz3MKtYQH8g(Unknown Source:0)
at org.example.myapp.tests.modules.generic.AddLinesActivityTests$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.execute(Unknown Source:6)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:205)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:187)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:205)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:205)
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:503)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:133)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:236)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:437)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:285)
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:503)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:133)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:236)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:437)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:285)
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:503)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:133)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:236)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:437)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:285)
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:503)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:133)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:236)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachOrdered(ReferencePipeline.java:442)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:205)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:187)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:205)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:205)
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:503)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:133)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:236)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:437)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:285)
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:503)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:133)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:236)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachOrdered(ReferencePipeline.java:442)
at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:179)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1528)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1528)
Caused by: androidx.test.espresso.AppNotIdleException: Looped for 26 iterations over 60 SECONDS. The following Idle Conditions failed DELAY_HAS_PAST.
at androidx.test.espresso.IdlingPolicy.handleTimeout(IdlingPolicy.java:5)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:50)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:1)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopMainThreadForAtLeast(UiControllerImpl.java:7)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.sendTap(Tap.java:6)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:6)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:2)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:25)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.-$$Nest$mdoPerform(Unknown Source:0)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:7)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:1)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
```

The relevant snippets:

```
androidx.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'single click - At Coordinates: 539, 553 and precision: 16, 16' on view ' displaying data matching: Item: cwms-testing-001 within adapter view matching: is assignable from class <class android.widget.AdapterView>'.
[...]
Caused by: androidx.test.espresso.AppNotIdleException: Looped for 26 iterations over 60 SECONDS. The following Idle Conditions failed DELAY_HAS_PAST.
```

As you see, it's a click on a totally different element that failed this time, and the `AppNotIdleException` says `DELAY_HAS_PAST` after 26 iterations.

And something I forgot to explain:

Since my tests mostly depend on successful completion of the previous test (to leave the UI in a state where the next test can continue), a single such failing test generally causes all tests from there on to fail as well.